# SceneKit Metal shader using ``clip_distance``

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal

I am modifying a SceneKit Metal shader given in https://medium.com/@MalikAlayli/metal-with-scenekit-create-your-first-shader-2c4e4e983300. It displays a cube with image texture, rendered by SceneKit with a Metal shader.

I changed the cube to a sphere of radius 3, centred at (0,0,0) using `SCNSphere(radius: 3)`. Then, I used `clip_distance` to "cut" away a portion of the sphere satisfying `in.position.z > 1.5`. The result is shown in the image below. The Metal shader I am using is also given below.

As you can see, the boundary is not smooth. It exhibits boundaries of polygons, instead of an interpolated surface. So, is it possible to make it smooth? If yes, how? Thank you.

[image]

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct NodeBuffer {
    float4x4 modelTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewTransform;
    float4x4 normalTransform;
    float2x3 boundingBox;
};

struct VertexInput {
    float3 position  [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
    float2 uv [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0)]];
};


struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
    float clip_distance [[clip_distance]];
};

vertex VertexOut textureSamplerVertex(VertexInput in [[ stage_in ]], constant NodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]]) {
    VertexOut out;
    out.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(in.position, 1.0);
    out.uv = in.uv;
    if ((in.position.z > 1.5)) {
        out.clip_distance = -1;
    }
    else {
        out.clip_distance = 1;
    }
    return out;
}

fragment float4 textureSamplerFragment(VertexOut out [[ stage_in ]], texture2d<float, access::sample> customTexture [[texture(0)]]) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler(coord::normalized, filter::linear, address::repeat);
    return customTexture.sample(textureSampler, out.uv );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The clip distances will be linearly interpolated across the primitive and the portion of the primitive with interpolated distances less than 0.0 will be clipped. ([gl_ClipDistance](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_ClipDistance.xhtml))

For the frontier of clipped fragments to be exactly at `z = 1.5` you need make sure that the interpolated clip distance is exactly at `0.0` when `z = 1.5` and then positive or negative on each side.

```cpp
out.clip_distance = (1.5 - in.position.z);
```